# solaris zfs won't import pools from another system after a system crash

Tags: solaris, zfs, import

attempted to import a couple zfs pools from another solaris 11.1 box that crashed hard.  the log device went corrupt but the disks are fine.  there weren't any writes to the system (it sits idle) so i'm not worried about missing data in memory.

attempted to install Solaris 11.3 and import the pools.  won't work.

tried zpool import -f and -m.

```
root@san:~# zpool import
  pool: zStorage2
    id: 714278190328663927
 state: UNAVAIL
status: One or more devices are unavailable.
action: The pool cannot be imported due to unavailable devices or data.
        The pool may be active on another system, but can be imported using
        the '-f' flag.
config:

        zStorage2                  UNAVAIL  corrupted data
          raidz1-0                 ONLINE
            c0t50014EE6AE05BA42d0  ONLINE
            c0t50014EE6AE06CB38d0  ONLINE
            c0t50014EE658B0A520d0  ONLINE
            c0t50014EE6035C3297d0  ONLINE
            c0t50014EE6035C9162d0  ONLINE

device details:

        missing-1                UNAVAIL          corrupted data
        status: ZFS detected errors on this device.
                The device has bad label or disk contents.


  pool: zStorage1
    id: 2650359371216878590
 state: UNAVAIL
status: One or more devices are unavailable.
action: The pool cannot be imported due to unavailable devices or data.
        The pool may be active on another system, but can be imported using
        the '-f' flag.
config:

        zStorage1                  UNAVAIL  corrupted data
          raidz1-0                 ONLINE
            c0t50014EE6AD900793d0  ONLINE
            c0t50014EE602E5703Dd0  ONLINE
            c0t50014EE602E53403d0  ONLINE
            c0t50014EE602E56418d0  ONLINE
            c0t50014EE602E56936d0  ONLINE

device details:

        missing-1                UNAVAIL          corrupted data
        status: ZFS detected errors on this device.
                The device has bad label or disk contents.
```

Comment: What was the log device?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your import command listed in the output.  The output of `zpool import` lists the other pools visible to the system.  In this case zStorage2 and zStorage1.

You'd need to run `zpool import -f <pool_name>` to try and import either of those pools.  You may also need to try using a `-F` option to try recovering a pool.  Using `-n` with the `-F` would tell if the recovery would be possible.  And kick off a scrub after the import.

If that doesn't help, you could open a case with Oracle to see if they could help with the recovery.

Comment: root@san:~# zpool import -Fn zStorage1
cannot import 'zStorage1': pool may be in use from other system,
it was last accessed by san (hostid: 0x4ef7e9) on Fri Oct 21 02:10:46 2016
: pool may already be in use

Comment: the use of zpool import -Fn returns the same error of pool being in use by another system. I'm wondering if zfs has been updated to address this problem?

Comment: @daft A bit late here, but the `n` option in  [`zpool import -Fn zStorage1`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29031/zpool-1m.html) means "don't actually do the import":  "`-n`    Used with the `-F` recovery option. Determines whether a non-importable pool can be made importable again, **but does not actually perform the pool recovery.** ..."